# Laravel Ajax Post returns 500

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I built an ajax post which sends each slider value (I am using jquery ui slider) to my controller.

The Ajax code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
        contentType: "application/json",
    url: "{{ Route('editProductPost', $product->id) }}",
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
        value: getSliderVal,
        productId : getPrId
    }),
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        // get response
        console.log(response.sliderValue)
    }
});
```

And in my Controller I am doing this:

```
public function editProductPost(Request $request)
{
    Log::info($request->get('value'));

    return view('product.edit', [
        'sliderValue' => $request->get('value')
    ]);
}
```

This returns me the correct slider value,

> Log::info($request->get('value'));

But I get this error message in my browser console:

> POST http://localhost/myApp/public/product/edit/98 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

Later on I want to call this `sliderValue` inside of a php loop in my view.

**Edit**

I do have a csrf token:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**Edit**

I have done this:

```
    $sliderValue = $request->get('value');
    $route = 'updateProduct';

    return view('product.edit', compact(['sliderValue', 'route']))->render();
```

The console print me `undefined` and if I do this `{{ sliderValue }}` I get an error that `sliderValue` is not defined

Comment: If you get Log::info($request->get('value')); value, then you should return json data instead of view.

Comment: @hizbul25 I had done this earlier but I can't use the variable in the view like that (in my php loop)

Comment: add `error:function(response){
console.log(response.responseText);
}`

Comment: This will get you the error that's causing the issue.

Comment: @jaysingkar thanks, that returns me alot in my console alot of html

Comment: you can add a temporary `<div id="errors"></div>` in your html and instead of `console.log()` add the `response.responseText` to that div.
`$('#errors').html(response.responseText);`

Comment: You will get the complete error in your current web page in proper format

Comment: @jaysingkar Thanks, I did that and my console returns alot of code bunch of html, css, js and php to much to show you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120488/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-john-doe-2).

Answer (score 0):

Little change of your code:

```
    public function editProductPost(Request $request)
    {
       Log::info($request->get('value'));
       $sliderValue = $request->get('value';

       return view('product.edit', compact('sliderValue'))->render();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I had this lines of code earlier, if I use those I do not get an error and the console returns the correct slider value, but I can not use `sliderValue` as a php variable in my view

Comment: I have made a change, please try it.

Comment: I get no error but an undefined, if I do this in my view `{{ $productEditview }}` I get an error undefined variable, any idea?

Comment: try again with new changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're returning a view in your controller. If your view used {{ $sliderValue }} inside it, it should work. But there's no way for javascript to get the sliderValue variable.

If you wanted the sliderValue as is, you can return this array

`return [
    'view' => view('product.edit', compact(['sliderValue', 'route']))->render(),
    'sliderValue' => $sliderValue
];`

That way you're sending to javascript an object with 2 properties, one should contain the view and the second one will only contain the value.

Comment: hmm ok do you mean that I cannot use the variable in php?